# Bridging header issues, Missing header files when run on device

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, fmdb, bridging-header

I have following lines on my Bridging-Header.h

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "FMDB.h"
#import "UAProgressView.h"
#import "ASValuePopUpView.h"
#import "ASValueTrackingSlider.h"
#import "JZMultiChoicesCircleButton.h"
#import "VYPlayIndicator.h"

#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

It works great with no errors when I run it on the simulator.
But when I run it on the device, it highlights with error "'FMDB.h' file not found". If you remove the line "for testing purpose" the error goes to the next line and so on.

What could be the problem when I run it on the device????!!!

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, select your project target, build setting and search for 'objective-c bridging header'. make sure the path equals the path of your bridging header file

Comment: Thats not whats he's asking

Comment: 'objective-c bridging header' is configured properly otherwise it won't run in first place on the simulator...